How to update values in all the cells using Java and Apache POI?
I use Apache POI to change some values in cells in an Excel workbook. This workbook has integrated formulas in some cells. These formulas use values from cells where I change the value. But I don't see any difference either in Apache POI or after saving in a file. I tried next actions:

I change a value in a cell
I save the workbook in a file.
I open this file using Microsoft Excel.
After that I see that the value in the cell, where I have changed it from the Apache POI, was successfully changed. But all the cells which must use this value as their input parameter were not changed. I need manually set some value in some cell to force "update" the worksheet.
How can I "update" all the cells content using Apache POI in according to formulas in the worksheet, after I have changed some values in some cells?


If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.
